# eclipse, c, auto increment build number define

Tags: c, eclipse, lpc, lpcxpresso

I'm using LPCXpresso (Eclipse) that is building C code for some MCU.
Is there some magic feature (plugin) that I can use to automatic increment a define?

```
#define  BUILD_NUMBER     1252       // auto increment at each build
```

Few years ago I wrote some simple exec for doing that on older IDEs (pre build events) but there may be a simpler solution now.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Your solution from a few years ago is more or less the "standard" solution for this purpose. You might want to use the `__DATE__` definition and `__TIME__` definition in addition your `BUILD_NUMBER` definition.

Comment: I know that Barak, it took me few hours to get CodeBlocks, build some exe that parse for some define and modify it. But I ask since Eclipse is such mature IDE (with millions of features btw. that I don't ever need) and I thought there must be a feature or something. Even VS have this very easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can this to use to store your build number and create an header at a pre-build stage by makefile, eg:

```
@id=`cat .build_id`; id=$$[id+1]; printf "#define BUILD_NUMBER\t\t0x%08X\n" $$id >> $@; echo "$$id" > .build_id
```

You can also add date and time, eg:

```
@printf "#define BUILD_DATE\t\t0x%04X%02X%02X\n" `date +"%-Y %-m %-d"` >> $@;
@printf "#define BUILD_TIME\t\t0x%02X%02X%02X\n" `date +"%-H %-M %-S"` >> $@;
```

Comment: I thought so (make) but I use automatic make file generated by project.
Can I use your hints by not altering originally make file?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: @user1797147 Are you talking about autotools project?

Comment: I guess not, I use Eclipse on Windows, customized by microcontroller manufacturer (NXP) and is called LPCXpresso. It's a standard C build project where make file is automatically generated by IDE.

Comment: I don't want to alter this make file since in developing process will be overwritten by IDE.